# Python Tkinter set not updating with new ID's when shift key is used to allow 'multi-select'

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm building an app using python and tkinter that allows a user to select boxes drawn on a canvas. I am trying to implement a 'multi-select' feature where the user may hold down the shift key and then select multiple bboxes on the canvas, the ID's for each new box is then stored in a set (`self.selected_bboxes = set()`) and dealt with later on in a separate function.

Box click event handler:

```
def on_bounding_box_click(self, event, bbox_id):
        if self.ctrl_pressed:
            if not self.field_bbox_id:
                self.field_bbox_id = bbox_id
                self.pdf_canvas.itemconfig(bbox_id, outline='green')  # Field selection
            elif not self.value_bbox_id and bbox_id != self.field_bbox_id:
                self.value_bbox_id = bbox_id
                self.pdf_canvas.itemconfig(bbox_id, outline='yellow')  # Value selection
        else:
            # If multi-select mode is enabled, allow for adding or removing from the selection
            if self.shift_pressed:
                if bbox_id in self.selected_bboxes:
                    self.selected_bboxes.remove(bbox_id)
                    self.pdf_canvas.itemconfig(bbox_id, outline=self.acc1)  # Deselect color
                    self.original_bbox_coords.pop(bbox_id, None)
                else:
                    self.selected_bboxes.add(bbox_id)
                    self.pdf_canvas.itemconfig(bbox_id, outline=self.acc2)  # Select color
                    self.original_bbox_coords[bbox_id] = self.pdf_canvas.coords(bbox_id)
            else:
                # If multi-select mode is not enabled, it should clear the selection and select the new one
                if bbox_id not in self.selected_bboxes:
                    for selected_id in list(self.selected_bboxes):  # Use list to avoid runtime error during iteration
                        self.pdf_canvas.itemconfig(selected_id, outline=self.acc1)  # Deselect color
                        self.original_bbox_coords.pop(selected_id, None)
                    self.selected_bboxes.clear()
                    self.selected_bboxes.add(bbox_id)
                    self.pdf_canvas.itemconfig(bbox_id, outline=self.acc2)  # Select color
                    self.original_bbox_coords[bbox_id] = self.pdf_canvas.coords(bbox_id)
                else:
                    # If the bbox is already selected and multi-select mode is not enabled, deselect it
                    self.selected_bboxes.remove(bbox_id)
                    self.pdf_canvas.itemconfig(bbox_id, outline=self.acc1)  # Deselect color
                    self.original_bbox_coords.pop(bbox_id, None)
            print(self.selected_bboxes)
            # Set the start drag data for the movement
        self.start_drag_data = {'x': event.x, 'y': event.y}
```

The ctrl pressed section is for another feature.

When I run the app and read the print statements only the ID of the box I click on currently is printed in the set (each line is a new print showing a set containing only one ID):

```
{3}
{4}
{5}
{9}
{9}
{10}
{9}
{10}
{9}
{10}
{11}
{15}
{24}
{77}
{79}
```

Misc code:

```
self.bind('<Shift_L>', self.on_shift_press)
self.bind('<KeyRelease-Shift_L>', self.on_shift_release)

...

def on_shift_press(self, event):
    self.shift_pressed = True

def on_shift_release(self, event):
    self.shift_pressed = False
```

I've been trying to debug it using print statements but I cannot figure out why the set isn't updating, I also tried to implement the same logic using a dictionary instead of a set but the dictionary wouldn't update either.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that `self.shift_pressed` is being set?  My first guess would be that you might be binding the shift key events on a widget that isn't the keyboard focus, which would prevent them from being called.  If that isn't it, search for `self.selected_bboxes =` and `self.selected_bboxes.clear()`, to make sure you're not clearing the set at some inappropriate point.

Comment: It is not known when and how `on_bounding_box_click()` is called.  It is better to provide a [mre].

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).